# Power bI multiple tables line chart

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am pretty new to BI and have had to make a chart showing running totals of fields from multiple tables, where one table is a summary of monthly anticipated spend and the other contains thousands of individual orders.

I have managed to plot the multiple running totals on the chart, but it's pretty much dumb data, I can filter the orders by budget header but the budget data remains showing the whole year for all the data instead of just the duration and data for the grass cutting works for example.

Is it possible to filter two tables on one value in one chart does anyone know?

Many thanks

Wayne

Answer (score 0):

Wayne, welcome to StackOverflow!  Disclaimer - I am a novice with PowerBI myself.  However, I think that I understand what you are asking here, so will make an attempt to help.

Sounds like your first step should be to get all of your data on the same basis (monthly) and then link the two tables.  The most intuitive way to do this would be to create a copy of the second table (orders) within the Power Query Editor ("Home" > "Edit Queries"), group its data into the same structure as the first table (right-click > Group By...), "Merge Queries" in top-right corner in order to connect to the first table (monthly budget / anticipated), then expand to bring in the data you need from the first table into the second table.

It is not really possible for me to give you more detailed steps without at least some insight on what your data looks like (be sure to redact appropriately).  I would also recommend taking an intro course on PowerBI such as the one offered by edX [here](https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:Microsoft+DAT207x+1T2018a/course/) as it does a great job on covering the how-to of this type of data wrangling.